# Best suitable multiple select with optgroup UI element

Tags: usability, gui-design, multi-selection

My website has a drop-down list that displays all countries, grouped by continent.
A user has to select all the countries he needs, as shown in the following figure:

[image: Drop-down list]

The main issue here is the user cannot click on a continent label and select all its countries.
Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Surely there's no reason why clicking on a continent _couldn't_ select its countries, if that would be the most usable solution? It's just a case of implementing that behaviour. That would be an off-topic discussion though.

Comment: Of course it's possible to implement this behaviour, but I'm curious to know if there are better solutions out there.

Answer (score 2):

Continent label has a different style than the rest of the list, it has a header style so it will be strange if it's also clickable.

An easy win could be to include in the first row of each continent group something like: "All countries", in the way when it's clicked will select the whole continent.